# Exhaustion function $\lim_{z\to a}f(z)=\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ be a domain.

The following proposition is true?

There is a holomorphic function $f\in H(U)$ such that for all $a\in\partial U$$$\lim_{z\to a}f(z)=\infty$$

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: [Crossposted on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/q/225141/21564).

Comment: The question at MO is somewhat different (there $U$ is a domain of holomorphy in $\mathbb{C}^n$, and $f$ may depend on the choice of $a$.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose there is such an $f$ with $U=\mathbb D.$ Show that $f$ has only finitely many zeros. This implies there is a nonzero $g$ holomorphic on $\mathbb D$ with the same property. Think about $1/g$ and the maximum modulus theorem.

Comment: The same argument works for every domain that is (conformally equivalent to) a bounded domain. On the other hand if we take $U = \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \}$, we can simply take $f(z) = 1/z$.